# Trying to put logo image above the full width menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im starting to study bootstrap and Im here with a doubt.

I want to have a full width menu and above this menu I want my logo.

I already have the menu like I want but my image is inside the menu, and I want the image above.

And I know this is happening because I have image inside the menu div, but I also want my image inside the `<div class="container">` because I study that the elements inside this div stay centered..and that is my objetive.

I already tried to pass this code above the `<div class="row navbar">` but didnt work like I want:

```
<div class="span3">
      <div class="area_logo">
          <a href="index.php">
           <img src="logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo" width="527" height="72">
          </a>
      </div>
```

Anyone there with bootstrap exprience can give a help?

**My html:**

```
    <div class="row navbar">
            <div class="span9">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" title"Home">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" title"Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" title"Home"Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" title"Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" title"Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" title"Home">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My css:**

```
body{ font-size:100%; padding:0;}

/*TOP*/
.top{background:blue; height:50px; width:100%;}
.top .area_logo{position:relative; }
.top .logo {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

**My fiddle with the code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/s6ZPm/8/

What I want but inside the div container to be always centered in other devices:
Deftones is like a logo and menu is the dark background below:s
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my menu code is that row navbar...I dont have any menu item yet, for now I just have the background!

Comment: check this examples in bootstrap docs, http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: and chose what do you want, create a menu just for learn, show the code, and after that we can help you to customize, because menus in bootstrap have diferent options.

Comment: I'm still not following what you're looking for. Are you referring to something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s6ZPm/10/

If not, you're going to have to whip up a crude image or something to illustrate what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to give any real feedback since your menu code isn't displayed, [but is this what you're looking for?](http://www.bootply.com/127392)

All you really need to do is place the image inside of the container, or directly inside the navbar itself. Keep in mind, when the menu collapses you'll need to adjust the positioning slightly as you'll have something like this:

[image: example of bootstrap menu alignment with logo]

Luckily, it's a simple fix. You can control this by setting float on the logo so the menu wraps next to it. I've included a media query in this bootply for that scenario. You'll also need to adjust the buttons position some. That can be accomplished with a little bit of margin adjustment. Once that's done, you're looking good:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! But its not that! I will update with what Im trying! Sorry give you a lot of work without having explained it well :/

Comment: @Skelly Cool, thanks! I don't use bootply much, had no idea you could do that.